# How to add view From a helper class

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a helper class called `FunctionHelper.m`.

I implemented some methods I would like to reuse. One of them is giving me some issues.

```
+(UIActivityIndicatorView *) InitActivityIndicator{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator  = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:
                                                   UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    //[activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0)];
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    activityIndicator.color = [UIColor redColor];
    //[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];

    return activityIndicator;
}
```

I am not able to compile the code,  when I try to access the `View` size or add a `view`.

The function is working as is, Im just not able to manipulate. I tried inheriting from `UIViewController` but it did not help. Please advice.

Comment: You cannot access self.view because it is a class method.

Comment: Not only this is a class method, it seems like it's not an UIViewController class method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you put this method in the helper class, because you may want to use this for different view controllers.

So i would suggest to change for your method like this

```
+(void) AddActivityIndicatorOnView: (UIView *)view{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator  = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:
                                               UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    [activityIndicator setCenter:CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width/2.0, view.frame.size.height/2.0)];
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    activityIndicator.color = [UIColor redColor];
    [view addSubview:activityIndicator];
}
```

So whenever you need to add the activity Indicator, simply pass the view into the method like this

```
[FunctionHelper AddActivityIndicatorOnView:self.view];
```

I don't know if i understand your questions correctly, if there is anything missing, feel free to leave in the comments.

Comment: I dont know why I didnt think about this , thanks a lot